# Why declare viewport in html email campaign?

Tags: email, html-email, viewport, meta

The majority of HTML emails and boilerplate that I've seen coded by other people, always declare a viewport meta tag.

I mindfully always avoid declaring a viewport and strive for a very high level of cross/backwards compatibility.

Declaring viewport settings render the email totally unusable for any of your audience using a Blackberry and overall is very poorly supported by any client.

Is there a reason to use this tag that I missed?  Why are the majority of other peoples emails I see using this?

---

Additional Reference:  http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/emailology_viewport_metatag_rendered_unusable

Answer (score 4):

If you want blackberry to work then by all means do not declare your viewport tag. Also don't nest tables, that will break the layout on blackberry too.

however, your other (vast majority of) mobile users will suffer. They will be able to pinch and zoom which can break your layout, I've also heard of resizing issues on high ppi screens without viewport, and I've had problems with horizontal scroll bars on my emails when I tried to go without it as well.

My current client has a huge email list. I forget the precise open stats, but versus the iphone and android's 100-140k opens each, blackberry opens accounted for 400.

of course one of their higher ups (above our contact for them) was the guy that just would not get rid of his ancient rolly ball blackberry and was pretty upset that he wasn't seeing anything. It took a while for us to convince them that dropping legacy blackberry support was the right move.

Comment: In what way is zooming breaking your layout?  I've never experienced this problem.

Comment: Im also curious to know how client zooming it breaks layout. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `<meta name="viewport">` tag is required **on the Web** to get web pages to be able to be responsive. But as you suggested, this is true **on the Web** and for Web browsers. But what about in HTML emails and in email clients?

In my experience (from being an email developer for 15+ years and maintaining resources like [email-bugs](https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/) and [Can I email](https://www.caniemail.com/)), the `<meta name="viewport">` is not required for creating responsive emails in email clients. Most email client families (like Apple Mail, Gmail, Outlook) have custom heuristics to automatically make the viewport ready for responsive or force the viewport to a specific width depending on the content of the email. Having the `<meta name="viewport">` makes zero difference there.

A viewport declaration used to be required to get your emails to be responsive in Outlook on Windows Phone 8. But they only supported the CSS declaration of viewport (`@viewport`), not the `<meta>` version. This needed to be accompanied with the `X-UA-Compatible` meta to force the app to use IE11's rendering engine. And the viewport's value needed to be defined in exact pixels as the `device-width` keyword wasn't supported.

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<style>
@viewport { width: 320px; }
</style>
```

A common issue nowadays can happen in Apple Mail where it doesn't properly scale your email to fit the screen. (Again, this happens whether or not you have the `<meta name="viewport">` tag.) You can [find examples of this issue in this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/18). The fix is to add the following tag inside the `<head>` of your email.

```html
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
```

Still, not having the `<meta name="viewport">` can create situations where your email does not respond properly to the viewport when using your browser's responsive DevTools. It can also make your email non responsive when viewed in a browser if your "view in a browser" link uses the exact same code. This might be why most emails have the `<meta name="viewport">` nowadays, even though it is not required.

Answer (score -1):

Read this I hope this will help

http://dev.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972

The viewport meta is worth using as it is also used by

http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/ using the following values

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

Comment: This article is about web design.  It has nothing to do with HTML email design which is a totally different beast.

Comment: Thanks @dcc but up to best of my knowledge and understandings so far, viewport meta tag has vital role when you are viewing HTML email on mobile devices.

Kindly look into http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/ documentation they have used it too

Comment: I edited my question with a link to the article I referred to.  This is exactly why I'm confused.

Comment: I think htmlemailboilerplate his not a very good template if you need a wide range of cross compatibility besides only the newest and most popular clients.